# Unable to unzip in java using Zip4J

Tags: java, zip

Hello I'm from the Pacific Ocean on the other shore of China.
Please forgive my rudimentary English.
Screening of foreign websites causes even more problems.

In my current project I am using zip4j, but an issue arises. Here is my code:

```
public static File [] unzip(File zipFile, String dest, String passwd) throws ZipException {
    ZipFile zFile = new ZipFile(zipFile);
    zFile.setFileNameCharset("GBK");
    if (!zFile.isValidZipFile()) {
        throw new ZipException("压缩文件不合法,可能被损坏.");
    }
    File destDir = new File(dest);
    if (destDir.isDirectory() && !destDir.exists()) {
        destDir.mkdir();
    }
    if (zFile.isEncrypted()) {
        zFile.setPassword(passwd.toCharArray());
    }
    zFile.extractAll(dest);

    List<FileHeader> headerList = zFile.getFileHeaders();
    List<File> extractedFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    for(FileHeader fileHeader : headerList) {
        if (!fileHeader.isDirectory()) {
            extractedFileList.add(new File(destDir,fileHeader.getFileName()));
        }
    }
    File [] extractedFiles = new File[extractedFileList.size()];
    extractedFileList.toArray(extractedFiles);
    return extractedFiles;
}
```

The issue occurs when compressing package files after more than a certain number (my file 2000).
I used myeclipse development tools and tomcat server.

I used breakpoints in myeclipse, and did not experience any errors.
Without adding breakpoints, I got direct operation errors:

```
net.lingala.zip4j.exception.ZipException: Compressed file is not valid, can be damaged.
    at com.ninemax.cul.util.CompressUtil.unzip(CompressUtil.java:68)
    at com.ninemax.cul.util.CompressUtil.unzip(CompressUtil.java:38)
    at com.ninemax.cul.service.impl.SysShangChuanWenWuService.writeDataToDatabase(SysShangChuanWenWuService.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:311)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy48.writeDataToDatabase(Unknown Source)
    at com.ninemax.cul.action.web.UserUploadAction.uploadSuccess(UserUploadAction.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

Comment: is it always the same file that is causing errors? How big is are your files maybe your server memory reached it limits?

Comment: `com.ninemax.cul.util.CompressUtil.unzip(CompressUtil.java:68)` : what is in this line ? also if it is windows only maybe some encoding issue ? How are you reading/writing the files ? Are you using `PrintWriter` or `PrintReader`? Those take the system default encoding. Also : `in Windows environment appear error` - even when you unzip them normally (with windows programs like 7z) ?

Answer (score 0):

What is the tool which is used to create the ZIP File you are trying to extract?

Most probably your zip file is corrupted. Please check whether it is corrupted or not by trying to unzip it using a unzip tool like Winzip (Windows) or GUnzip (UNIX).

If it is not corrupted, then most probably the zip is Encrypted and Password protected using an Encryption method which is not supported by Zip4J. For instance Zip4J supports AES-256 bit Winzip Encryption/Decryption but doesn't support AES-256 PKZIP Encryption/Decryption.

Comment: File not damaged, with other decompression tool can normal unzip, in Java test class also call this method can also normal unzip, project in Linux environment can unzip, but in Windows environment appear error.                                                            Thank you for your answer, again looking forward to your answer